# is there an online reference guide for Workflow lookup fields?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I really need a better way than trial and error of figuring out what the different Define Workflow Lookup Data source and Fields are.  Is there a good book or online reference tool I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/define-a-workflow-lookup-HA010237830.aspx

It's for 2007 but still applies in 2010.

Comment: I just looked at this article, and it doesn't appear to answer the question. The article discusses, conceptually, how to use the workflow lookup dialog, but lacks any explanation of the fields that do not correspond to the columns exposed in the UI - for example, each individual field under "Workflow Context", and the "Current Item" fields `Edit Menu Table Start`, `Encoded Absolute URL`, and `Path`, among others. I'd really like to find a reference that enumerates and defines all the options that *don't* tie to a field whose value can easily be checked by opening the list/item in the browser.